# Starting Learn Python the Hard Way, and I cant open Python through Powershell?

Tags: python, powershell

I copied and pasted what he put on the website but no luck. This is what shows up-

```
python : Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 2.7.9 (d...ntel)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting out here as well, I got that error and it was because I was using "PowerShell ISE",  make sure to use the standard PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

number 6 states: "In your PowerShell (Terminal) program, run python. You run things in your terminal by typing the name and pressing Enter." [link.](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html)
  The above screen shot is the python interpreter that zed shaw is referring too. According to that screen shot you already have python 2.7.9 installed.